# print statement in python, a space is written before the object is writen unless

Tags: python

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> A space is written before each object is (converted and) written, unless the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of a line. This is the case (1) when no characters have yet been written to standard output, (2) when the last character written to standard output is a whitespace character except ' ', or (3) when the last write operation on standard output was not a print statement.

But I don't understand what the (2) means...

> when the last character written to standard output is a whitespace character except ' '

Comment: Whitespace includes more than just the space character.  Newline and tab are also whitespace.  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

This question could use some more context.  What part of the documentation is this from?  What are you trying to do?  What is it that you don't understand about the clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean any [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) other than the ASCII space character U+0020 SPACE (i.e. the character created when you press the space bar on a typical American keyboard).  In particular, this includes the carriage return, line feed (one or both of which may be created when pressing the enter key, depending on your operating system), horizontal and vertical tabs, and (perhaps) a variety of non-ASCII characters that the Unicode consortium has seen fit to create over the years, but which you are unlikely to encounter "in the wild" unless you go looking for them or allow the end user to supply you with arbitrary data.

Since you have not stated whether this is Python 2 or Python 3, it is not clear to me whether the system has enough information to recognize these non-ASCII characters when they are printed.  If, for example, you are using Python 2 and 8-bit strings, the system does not know what encoding you are using, and may not be able to deal with anything that doesn't closely follow ASCII.